# How to blit numbers in pygame?

Tags: pygame, numbers, geometry, blit

Currently, I am working on a game in which you are asked a mathematical question such as `2 + 1` and numbers will fall from the top of the screen. The player has to click the right answer before it falls below the screen. However, I don't want to download images of the numbers because it would waste lots of time. Is there a way to draw or blit numbers instead? If there is, can the numbers be in a circle shape instead of a rectangle?

**EDIT**: I could create the numbers by displaying them as text. However, that would mean I have to create hundreds of different rectangles for each possible answer. My question then is, is there a way for me to tell Python to generate numbers and place them on a rectangle without me having to do it manually?

Comment: I think it would be a good solution to create the answer objects (numbers) anew for each question. So create a class for the numbers  and then fill a list or sprite group with the instances when a new question gets asked, and clear the list afterwards.

Comment: BTW, it's usually required to show us what you've tried (a minimal, complete example). We don't want to (and should not) do someone else's homework.

Comment: i am quite new in this website. thank you for letting me know. Next time, i will try and put an example.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a class in which you store the actual answer, the text surface and the rect for the collision detection. I use a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) subclass here, but you can do the same with a normal class. When a new question gets asked, you can just create a bunch of instances and add them to a sprite group, so that you can update them altogether in the main loop. You can use the [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) method for the collision detection.

```
import random

import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)


class Answer(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, number):
        super().__init__()
        # Store the actual number, so that we can compare it
        # when the user clicks on this object.
        self.number = number
        # Render the new text image/surface.
        self.image = FONT.render(str(number), True, BLUE)
        # A rect with the size of the surface, used for collision
        # detection and rendering.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, random.uniform(1, 4))
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if self.rect.top > 480:  # Screen bottom.
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all groups.


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 3:  # Right mouse button.
                    # Add 20 numbers (Answer objects).
                    for _ in range(20):
                        number = random.randrange(100)
                        all_sprites.add(Answer((random.randrange(620), -20), number))
                elif event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                    # See if the user clicked on a number.
                    for answer in all_sprites:
                        # event.pos is the mouse position.
                        if answer.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                            print(answer.number)


        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

(Right click to spawn the numbers, left click to touch single numbers.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sorry, but i don't understand the class module. If you don't mind (and it would save time), where would u suggest learning this topic because i believe it's important

Comment: Program Arcade Games' [chapter 12](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=de&chapter=introduction_to_classes) and [13](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=de&chapter=introduction_to_sprites) about classes and pygame sprites are pretty good.